# how to code for multi possible routes from source to destination with highlighted shortest path

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i have mapped one possible route from source to destination,now i want to know how to code for multi possible routes from source to destination with highlighted shortest path, 
my tried code given below,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
double mLatitude = 0;
double mLongitude = 0;
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
int i = 0;
String loopValue = "";
TextView textView;
Location mLocation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_loop);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Map Ready");
    if(googleMap != null)
      mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                mGoogleMap.clear();
                    LatLng source = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng destination = latLng;

                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(source, destination);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                drawMarker(mMarkerPoints.get(0));
                drawMarker(latLng);

            }
        });


}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng source, LatLng destination) {

    String mSource = "origin=" + source.latitude + "," + source.longitude;
    String mDestination = "destination=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;
    String mSensor = "sensor=false";
    String mParameters = mSource + "&" + mDestination + "&" + mSensor;
    String mOutput = "json";
    String murl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + mOutput + "?" + mParameters;
    return murl;
}

private String downloadUrl(String mUrl) throws IOException {
    String mdata = "";
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(mUrl);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.connect();
        inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String mLine = "";
        while ((mLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(mLine);
        }
        mdata = stringBuffer.toString();
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception While downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return mdata;
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    if (mLocation == null) {
        mLocation = location;
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15));
        drawMarker(point);
        loopValue = "Loop : "+ i +" "+ mMarkerPoints.size()+"\n";
        textView.setText(loopValue);
        i++;
    }
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String mData = "";
        try {
            mData = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("Background Task", mData);
        return mData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> > {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser directionsJSONParser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
             routes = directionsJSONParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Result: "+result.toArray().toString()+" Result size: "+result.size());
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Loop: "+i);
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Loop inner: "+j);
                HashMap<String, String> latLngss = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latLngss.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(latLngss.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Hash : " + latLngss.toString());
                points.add(position);
            }
        }
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(points)
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.RED));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}

private void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
    mMarkerPoints.add(point);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(point);

    if (mMarkerPoints.size() == 1) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    } else if (mMarkerPoints.size() == 2) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    }
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
} }
```

DirectionsJSONParser.java

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(list.get(l).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(list.get(l).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return routes;
}
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }
    return poly;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also made a Google Maps App.
I had a lot of MTB(Mountain bike) trails and I decided to make  **Polyline**
This is part of my code:

```
  Polyline line = mapa.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(43.38, -5.849),
                    new LatLng(nextCoord),
                    new LatLng(nextCoord),
                    new LatLng(nextCoord))
                   .width(10)
                   .color(Color.GREEN));
```

So you will have a "path" marked up .

Comment: should not mention LatLag coordinates ;i drawn a polyline when a marker placed in location by clicking certain location; my task is to draw multi possible routes from source to destination.need multi polylines for same source to dest with different routes @David360

Comment: Oh! I see... I am not a level programmer in Android. Could you post a pic?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refrain from ending each of your answers with "please contact me", or by asking for upvotes. Such signatures are classed as noise, and should not be added.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice @Matt.